# adding a model to a joining table and calling it from a different model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say the has_many through is defined like this for a rails model.

```
class Physician < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
  has_many :tickets, through: :appointments #For calling **physicion.tickets**. Is this possible???
end

class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
  has_many :tickets, as: ticketable 
end

class Patient < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
end
```

This works fine. But let's add a ticket model to the appointment so each appointment can keep tickets belonging to that appointment.

```
class Ticket < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :ticketable, polymorphic: true #so it can be used in other models other than appointments
end
```

`appointment.tickets` works fine. But how can we fetch all tickets for a particular physician/patient like `physicion.tickets` or `patient.tickets`?

Comment: If *"`appointment.tickets` works fine"* than you're not showing us the `has_many :tickets` association in `Appointment`.  If that association is there `has_many :tickets, through: :appointments` in both `Physician` and `Patient` should work. Have you tried running your solution?

Comment: @3limin4t0r I changed the class models a bit for easy explaining and I think I removed the vital part aswell :). The ticket model is polymorphic. So its not working as I expect. Is there anything special that we need to do if its polymorphic, like defining class_names or so?

Comment: @3limin4t0r Fixed it. It was spring problem. Just stopped spring and its working now. Thank you. Stay safe